# Tkinter with another infinite loop ( For speech to text conversion)

Tags: python, tkinter, speech-recognition, infinite-loop, pocketsphinx

Tkinter GUI don't shows up when running in parallel with another infinity loop;i have tried Threading and multiprocessing techniques, whereas used GUI in main code and calling livespeech code or vice versa ; and defining both codes in function and calling from the main thread.But the problem remains; different result are attached below although u find it comment but have tried that method too,

```
    #*********************************** IMPORTING MODULES*****************
import tkinter
from tkinter import*
import tkinter.messagebox
import sqlite3
import os
from multiprocessing import Process
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech, get_model_path
import threading
from time import sleep

model_path = get_model_path()

#*************** TKINTER GUI CODE******************
def gui():
 window = tkinter.Tk()
 window.title("Smart Notice Board")

 top = Canvas(window,width=400,height=200)
 top.pack(fill=X)

 button_5 = Button(text='PORTAL SYSTEM', height = 2, width=17, activebackground = '#33B5e5', bg = 'brown', fg = 'white',command  = portal )
 top.create_window(80,80, anchor='nw', window = button_5)


def portal():
   print("2")



#****************  speech TO text CODE***************

def speech(): 
    speech = LiveSpeech(
        verbose=False,
        sampling_rate=16000,
        buffer_size=2048,
        no_search=False,
        full_utt=False,
        hmm=os.path.join(model_path, 'en-us'),
        lm=os.path.join(model_path, '8582.lm'),
        dic=os.path.join(model_path, '8582.dict')
    )

    for phrase in speech:
        print(phrase)
        a=str(phrase)
        print(a)

#************************** MAIN LOOP************************

if __name__ == "__main__":

    #************ FOR THREADING************
    #thread1 = threading.Thread(target=gui)
    #thread2 = threading.Thread(target=speech)
    #thread1.daemon = True
    #thread1.start()
    #thread2.start()

    #thread1.join()
    #thread2.join()


    #************ FOR MULTIPROCESSING****************

    #processes=[]
    #P1 = Process(target=gui)
    #P2 = Process(target=speech)
    #processes.append(P1)
    #processes.append(P2)
    #P2.daemon = True
    # Will execute both in parallel
    #P1.start()
    #P2.start()
    # Joins threads back to the parent process, which is this
    # program
    #P1.join()
    #P2.join()


    #****************** live speech code*************
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.title("Smart Notice Board")

    top = Canvas(window,width=400,height=200)
    top.pack(fill=X)

    button_5 = Button(text='PORTAL SYSTEM', height = 2, width=17, activebackground = '#33B5e5', bg = 'brown', fg = 'white',command  = portal )
    top.create_window(80,80, anchor='nw', window = button_5)
```

[image: both as fn and call from main loop]

[image: now livespeech in main loop and calling GUI,only livespeech works and GUI not shows up]

IN multiprocessing case; no error but nothing works

Comment: You're not calling Tkinter's .mainloop().

Comment: Thanks,i have made the mentioned mistake; still I have to use GUI as thread and LIvespeech as main thread it works fine; till I interface IF cond to show button on specific word ,,, then it gives error that GUI is not in the main thread. I have to use speech as main thread otherwise it gives error that signal should be in the main thread. Also please take a look in multiprocessing code as it doesn't work and shows no error

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to get mouse move event's cursor position from queue and act accordingly:

```
def check_mouse(self):
    while True:
        item = self.mouse.get_item()
        if item is None:
            break
        else:
            self.master.after_idle(self.mouse_move, *item)

    self.master.after(INTERVAL, self.check_mouse)
```

and it's first time called just before mainloop call, with yet another `self.master.after(INTERVAL, self.check_mouse)`.

So make you Tkinter GUI do its work in the mainloop and you should create another loop with a task that will run after INTERVAL (in miliseconds) and it will call itself every INTERVAL period after its job is finished.

Comment: Ooh i see, so i can make GUI in main loop but cannot figure out how to write speech to text code in another loop;I have to do similar work as when some phrase is captured then it have to do some task otherwise it have no work. Also wherever i call tkinter mainloop code freezes there and when i close it then it goes on next line. Could u help me write the code for speech to text in loop?

Comment: I guess you could try that logic with your for loop instead of while True here.